# container instances are not joining the correct cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, launch, amazon-ecs

So I have 2 clusters `aws-docker-cluster` for my frontend code & `aws-docker-cluster-2` for my backend API on AWS. However, I can't figure out how to add 2 EC2 instances to each. I created 2 Security Groups, 2 Target Groups, 2 Load Balancers, 2 Launch Configurations, & 2 Autoscaling Groups but I keep getting situation 1 where all 4 instances getting added to the same cluster `aws-docker-cluster` like so:

[image]

or creating a default cluster like so:
[image]

While making the launch configuration for `aws-docker-cluster-2` I made sure to add to following to the user data under advanced details:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=aws-docker-cluster-2 >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

But it doesn't work. What else am I missing?

Comment: Did you specify `--env-file=/etc/ecs/ecs.config` as part of your launch parameters when starting the `amazon-ecs-agent`? Are these new instances (user data only runs at launch)?

Comment: If they're creating a "Default" cluster, it means either ecs.config is not being read by ecs-agent or ECS_CLUSTER field is empty or not present. Have a look at journal log and see if user data script is being executed without issues (been there). Sometimes the script does not run or exits before completing all steps. Also, as @MrDuk said, user data scripts are run only in launch time, so it won't execute in existing instances.